# Automating filling in input fields and clicking a button using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to create a flight scraper between two locations using google flights.

I have tried the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver

if __name__ == "__main__":
  driver=webdriver.Chrome()
  driver.get('https://www.google.com/travel/flights')
  driver.maximize_window()

  where_from = driver.find_element('xpath',
                               '/html/body/c-wiz[2]/div/div[2]/c-wiz/div[1]/c-wiz/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/input')
  where_from.send_keys('Sydney')
  where_to = driver.find_element('xpath',
                                 '/html/body/c-wiz[2]/div/div[2]/c-wiz/div[1]/c-wiz/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/input')
  where_to.send_keys('Auckland')
  driver.implicitly_wait(30)
  search = driver.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/c-wiz[2]/div/div[2]/c-wiz/div[1]/c-wiz/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/button/div[1]')
  search.click()
```

I am trying to open up a web browser (chrome) and fill up the where from and where to input fields and click search. The where from and where to fields get filled in, but the search doesn't seem to work

Comment: using X path is not a good idea, as it can change, since Google is using AJAX it is not a fixed table design you should use beautifulsoup4

Comment: @jcruzer How are you supposed to click the Search button with beautifulsoup4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They didn't make that easy... You have to click the From, then use `.send_keys()`, then down arrow and ENTER. Same thing for the To. The code below is working.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.google.com/travel/flights')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[aria-placeholder='Where from?'] input"))).click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[aria-label='Enter your origin'] input"))).send_keys("Sydney" + Keys.ARROW_DOWN + Keys.ENTER)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[aria-placeholder='Where to?'] input"))).click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[aria-label='Enter your destination'] input"))).send_keys("Auckland" + Keys.ARROW_DOWN + Keys.ENTER)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Search']"))).click()

driver.quit()
```